# 2 Passports Moscow Transit

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, moscow

I have Japanese and Hong Kong SAR (HK) passport. Flying from HK to London and have a 17hr layover in Moscow and would like to go check the city.

My current UK visa is with my Japanese passport and my Japanese passport will require visa to enter Russia however my HK passport is visa free.

So the question is should I book my flight and enter Russia with my HK passport. And leave Russia with my HK passport and enter UK with my Japanese passport? Will it be an issue at arrivals in the UK since my booking details shows different passport?

Answer (score 4):

It will be no problem at the UK Border, the staff there do not know about your booking details. Anyway, it is quite normal to hold dual nationality especially at Heathrow.

BTW, I believe you can enter the UK on a HK (SAR) passport for up to six months. Is there a reason you prefer to enter on your Japanese passport? Or am I mistaken?

If so, I would show the Japanese passport to the airline to satisfy the airline that you will be admitted to the UK without a problem.

You can enter Russia by following the exit/arrivals/domestic flights sign (instead of international transit) and show the immigration inspector your HK SAR passport.

When you leave Russia you should show your Japanese passport to the airline check in desk again, but make sure you show the exit control your HK SAR passport. Since you entered Russia on the HK SAR passport you should ensure you are stamped out in the same passport.

If there are any problems or confusion you should be honest, it is not unusual to carry multiple passports.

(However, I did not know that Japan allows dual nationality.)

Comment: Japan allows dual nationality until you are 22.  While technically prohibited after reaching that age, in practice there is near-zero enforcement and (AFAIK) there are no recorded cases of anybody involuntarily losing their Jp citizenship due to acquiring another.